# Необходимо сделать так, чтобы по нажатию на диалог с тем или иным пользователем осуществлялся переход

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Есть система диалогов.

Происходит вывод самого последнего сообщения для конкретного пользователя.

Необходимо сделать так, чтобы по нажатию на диалог с тем или иным пользователем осуществлялся переход на страницу, где отображается история всей переписки с данным пользователем.

Трудность состоит в том, что я не знаю, как сделать так, чтобы по нажатию на диалог система понимала какой это пользователь.

Пример кода:

```
    $recipient = $_SESSION['username'];


    $query = "SELECT last_message, sender, date FROM dialogs where recipient = '$recipient' || sender = '$recipient' ";
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $query) or die(mysqli_error($db));

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) >0) {
    for ($data = []; $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result); $data[] = $row);

    $result = '';
    foreach ($data as $elem) {
        $result .= '<td>' . $elem['recipient'] . '</td>';
        $message.= '<h1 id ="read_message"> Message:'.$elem['last_message']. '</h1>'.'<h1 id ="sender"> Sender:'.$elem['sender'].'<br>' .'</h1>'.'<h1 id ="date"> Date:'.$elem['date'].'<br>' .'</h1>'.'<hr>' ;
        $_SESSION ['nomessage'] = "";
    }
}else{
    $_SESSION ['nomessage'] = "You don't have any message yet";

}  
?>
```

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, пример Вашего кода, чтобы имелась возможность ответить на Ваш вопрос. Вам надо просто на тег `<a>` добавить в `href` передачу параметра `GET`, в котором будет содержаться либо `id` клиента из сессии, либо другой параметр, который позволит определить принадлежность к определённым сообщениям.

Comment: Здравствуйте, добавил пример кода.